# How to save external API's data in a django model?

Tags: python, json, django, rest, api

I am pulling in some JSON data from a external API.

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "body": "example json"
},
{
   "id": 2,
   "body": "example json"
}
```

my User model:

```
class User(models.Model):
      body = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

how i can save the json response into my model ?

Answer (score 2):

Save a model defined object by using the [Model API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/)

```py
import json

json_result = '''{
   "id": 2,
   "body": "example json"
}'''
data = json.loads(json_result) # first convert to a dict
id = data.get("id") # get the id
body = data.get("body") # get the body
user = User.objects.create(id=id, body=body) # create a User object
user.save() # save it
```